# Invalid WI-FI Networks showing in "WI-FI Networks" list

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, moto-x

In my WI-FI list, I see 5 password protected WI-FI networks that appear to be in range. The problem is, I know these networks are not in range. It appears as if I was in range at some point and when I got out of range they did not go away. They show as available at home, at work(20 minutes from home), at the cottage(2 hours north of here) and anywhere else that I go.

I have never connected to these and I do not know the password to any of them. If I press and hold on them, the only option I have is "Connect to a network" so I cannot "Forget" them as I was never connected in the first place.

What could have caused these to start appearing in the list? Is there a way to get these out of my available "WI-FI Networks" list?

Comment: Do you have root access on your device? While I cannot answer the "why", I might be able to show a way to make them "go away" then.

Comment: I do not have root access on my device.

Comment: A pity. With root, you could use a "scalpel" to solve that (editing a single file – `/data/system/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant`, if I remember the path correctly). Without root, just "atomics" for all I know (i.e. a factory-reset would cure it; I don't know of any way to edit/reset the `wpa_supplicant` without root apart from that).

Comment: So the file `wpa_supplicant` is supposed to hold the wi-fi networks that are currently in range?

Comment: Looks like I've missed that part of your question. All networks *you've connected to in the past* are stored in a file called `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` (I've just checked the location again). Those you've not been connected to are not saved to that file. No idea where those are stuck – but I've had a similar case with one of my devices as well in the past. I don't remember how I've got rid of them; but you could try switching to airplane mode for a few seconds, that might trigger some "purge".

Comment: Airplane mode did the trick! Post is as an answer and I'll accept it. I've turned WI-FI on and off, restarted the phone, and just about everything else I could think of without any luck in this. I never thought Airplane mode would do anything different than turning these off. Maybe the combination of all of these being off at once? Thank you so much for your help! This has been driving me crazy for a few weeks.

Comment: Quite confusing. Turning WiFi off/on alone should be sufficient, let alone restarting the phone. Would be interesting to know what airplane mode adds to that. But hey, as long as it works (and is even less nasty than a reboot), let's gladly accept it solves the issue :) Answer placed as requested. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While all networks *you've connected to in the past* are stored in a file called `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`, networks "just seen" around (but never connected to) are IMHO not stored to any file, but just "cached" in memory. So a simple trick to get rid of them is to enter [airplane-mode](/questions/tagged/airplane-mode) for a couple of seconds (or a minute if seconds are not enough). With WiFi being disabled, the system should see no reason to "stick" to that "cached" information, and thus "forget" the unknown networks. As soon as you return from airplane mode, it would need to "rebuild" its cache again – but those "stickies" should be gone for good (until next time, maybe, but then simply repeat the action).

Comment: This worked great. I only needed to leave it on for a few seconds. Thanks for the help!